# Doesn't show the needed info from auth.log file when using grep

Tags: linux, grep, auth.log

I want to get all info about user from auth.log file, but when I use `grep user /var/log/auth.log` but instead of giving me all the information with user mentioned, it just writes to me `Binary file /var/log/auth.log matches`. It used to pick up the sentences with mentioned user, but now it doesn't.

Comment: try `grep -a user /var/log/auth.log`  it may help you.  `-a, --text`
              Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your auth.log has some garbage in it that is making grep believe it is binary, perhaps some UTF-8 encoded data.

Either way, grep has a switch to make it treat it as text anyway

`grep -a pattern /var/log/auth.log`